CSS pseudo elements appearance error when i try to use transform or z-index
While I was trying to create a specific shape using CSS to practice what I learned about the transform property, especially the rotate property, but I encountered a problem, which is that when I try to apply the property to the parent element, the background of the elements overlaps the background of the parent element. The strange thing is that the text in the parent does not disappear, but remains visible.
The shape I tried to make 
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: bisque;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative; 
  /* Problem is here */
  /* 
  transform: rotate(1deg);
  z-index: 999; 
  */
}

div::before {
  content: "";
  background-color: chocolate;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: rotate(5deg);
}

div::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: bisque;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -2;
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
}


Try it here 
With a little research, I discovered that the transform property invalidates the z-index, and yet no matter how high the values ​​I give the parent element, the problem remains.
